# Switching from graphql-js to native graphql schemas?

Tags: graphql

Currently trying to switch from `graphql-js` to literal GraphQL types/schemas, I'd like to know if anyone has had any experience with this.

Let's take this really simple one :

```js
const Person = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Person',
  fields: () => ({
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      description: 'Person name',
    },
  }),
});
```

I'd like to switch to the native GraphQL schema syntax i.e

```js
type Person {
  # Person name 
  name: String
}
```

However this would have to be incremental, and given the use of `graphql-js`, the best solution for now would be to parse GraphQL template literals to `GraphQLObjectType` (or any other type for that matter). Does anyone have experience doing this, I cannot seem to find any library for it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { printType } from 'graphql';

printType(Person)
```

output:

```js
type Person {
  """Person name"""
  name: String
}
```

Here is the demo:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { printType, printSchema, buildSchema, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';

import { logger } from '../util';
import { Person } from './';

describe('test suites', () => {
  it('convert constructor types to string types', () => {
    const stringTypeDefs = printType(Person).replace(/\s/g, '');
    logger.info(printType(Person));

    const expectValue = `
      type Person {
        """Person name"""
        name: String
      }
    `.replace(/\s/g, '');
    expect(stringTypeDefs).to.be.equal(expectValue);
  });

  it('buildSchema', () => {
    const stringTypeDefs = printType(Person);
    const schema = buildSchema(stringTypeDefs);

    expect(schema).to.be.an.instanceof(GraphQLSchema);
  });

  it('printSchema', () => {
    const stringTypeDefs = printType(Person);

    const schema = printSchema(buildSchema(stringTypeDefs));

    logger.info(schema);

    const expectValue = `
      type Person {
        """Person name"""
        name: String
      }
    `.replace(/\s/g, '');

    expect(schema.replace(/\s/g, '')).to.be.eql(expectValue);
  });
});
```

source code:

https://github.com/mrdulin/nodejs-graphql/blob/master/src/convert-constructor-types-to-string-types/index.spec.ts

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, for our case we want it the other way around. But thank you, I skipped the ’graphql-js’ utilities, seems like there is ’buildSchema’ which is perfectly indicated here :)

Comment: @AlexandreGomes Sorry. Did I understand your question correctly? I understood that you want to convert `constructor object type definition` to `string type definition`?

Comment: That's what I want to do in the project indeed, moving the types codebase `GraphQL schema language.`. But for that to be achieved, it is needed to have a way to convert `GraphQL Schema language` to `Schema object`. Could you modify your answer to point to the `buildSchema` utility, so I can accept it as an answer ?

Comment: Good ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [graphql-cli](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-cli) to extract a native graphql schema from a graphql server. All you need to do is..

1. Download the tool | `npm i -g graphql-cli`
2. Run `graphql init` in the directory of your project to
   create **.graphqlconfig** file
3. Start your graphql server
4. Run `graphql get-schema` and this will generate a your schema in native graphql

SAMPLE **.graphqlconfig**

```
{
  "projects": {
    "my_sample_project": {
      "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
      "extensions": {
        "endpoints": {
          "local": "http://localhost:8080/graphql"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We leverage the auto-generation of graphql schema/[queries/mutations](https://github.com/timqian/gql-generator#readme) for our CI workflows.